# SQL Query to get any column who's value can be Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Would anybody be able to shed some light on how i go about getting only columns who's type are Bit ( bool ) without having to set limits on queries?
I am currently able to return every column but that will confuse the built in Query in my program if an int column gets selected.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM databasex.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE [..?..]
```

any help or advice would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag your question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
information_schema.columns
 where data_type='bit'
```

Comment: well I feel daft now, I'd tried that but used
bit instead of 'bit'
thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, you can query the `sys.columns` and `sys.types` views

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
    c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS t
    ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE 
    t.name = 'bit'
```

Comment: Thanks, above answer is more appropriate for what i need it for but will refer to this for later work.
thanks again